# Change normal checkbox to a custom one and make them behave as radio buttons

Tags: html, css

I want to change my normal checkbox looks to as shown below. Please help me with the same.[image]

Image (5) shows not active checkbox and (6) shows checked checkbox.

Current code being used is as below:

```
<div class="x-form-cb-li x-form-cb-li-h" style="padding-bottom: 5px">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-checkbox x-form-field" id="optIn-Y" name="optIn" value="Y" style="float:left"><label class="x-form-cb-label" for="optIn-Y">Yes, please send me interesting offers</label>
</div>
```

To add to the above query. How can I make 2 such checkboxes to behave as radio buttons i.e. if the second one is clicked the first one is no longer checked and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

It shows how you can put a checkbox as a radio button:

```js
$('.select-option').click(function(){
  $(this).find('i').toggle();
  var checked=$(this).find('input').prop('checked');
  $(this).find('input').prop('checked',!checked);
  if(!checked){
    $(this).siblings().each(function(){
      $(this).find('input').prop('checked',false);
      $(this).find('i').first().show();
      $(this).find('i').last().hide();
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.select-option{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class='select-group'>
  <span class="select-option">
    <input type="checkbox" style="display: none">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" style="display: none;color:#428bca;"></i>         
  </span>
  <span class="select-option">
    <input type="checkbox" style="display: none">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" style="display: none;color:#428bca;"></i>         
  </span>
  <span class="select-option">
    <input type="checkbox" style="display: none">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" style="display: none;color:#428bca;"></i>         
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and thinks.

```js
$('.select-option').click(function(){
  $(this).find('i').toggle();
  $(this).find('input').prop('checked',!$(this).find('input').prop('checked'));
});
```

```css
.select-option{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<span class="select-option">
  <input type="checkbox" style="display: none">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" style="display: none;color:#428bca;"></i>         
</span>
```

Comment: To add to the above query. How can I make 2 such checkboxes to behave as radio buttons i.e. if the second one is clicked the first one is no longer checked and vice versa.

Comment: I have the answer but first you have to put my answer a good answer (please vote)